# Why my save method always giving exception not saving values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 3 models on my system

```
Public class Company {Id,Name}//Already have data

Public Class User {Id, Name}//Already have data

Public Class Department {Id,Name,CompanyId,UserId,Public Company Companies,Public User Users}
```

now I want to create a Seed data for my Department Model.
Code inside my seed data class;

```
if(!context.Department.Any()){

try {
var departments = new Department[]{
 new Department{ComapnyId=context.Companies.Single(s => s.Name=="Stackoverflow").Id,
     UserId =context.Users.Single(s => s.Name=="Admin").Id, Name="IT"}
};
  foreach (Department department in departments)
                        {
                            context.Department.Add(department);                         
                        }
                        context.SaveChanges();
}catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }//End Try and Catch
}//End If
```

Now my problem save method always drop an exception.

What am I doing wrong??

My Stacktrace:`at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---`

Comment: Which exception do you get?

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll

Comment: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: Exceptions occur for a reason, you need to take a second or 2 and read the type and the message. If the exception's message states `See the inner exception for details` then you should do that...

Comment: You need to read the exception's **message**. The stack trace is not so interesting in this case.

Comment: Thanks I managed to get a solution for my problem the data I was trying to insert was longer than the length I set on my db

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly configure your relashions between your models as below;

- Each user will have one company and one department
- Each Department will have one company and many users
- Each company will have many users and many departments

So, your data models must be like below:

```cs
public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

Public class Department {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Company {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

later on we can see what error you are facing.

Comment: Problem I only want to store only the names on table User and only company names on table company then on my Department table I link userto company and give the name of the department